# Get list of ArrayList

Tags: java, spring

I want to create a ArrayList of data and return it via Rest point. I tried this:

```
@Service
public class CardBrandsListService {

    public ArrayList<String> getCardBrandsList() {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("visa");
        list.add("master");
        list.add("Intl Maestro");
        list.add("amex");

        return list;
    }
}
```

Rest endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/card_brand/list")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getCurruncy() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(cardBrandsListService.getCardBrandsList().entrySet().stream()
                .map(g -> new CardBrandsListDTO(g.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
```

DTO:

```
public class CardBrandsListDTO {

    private String card_brand;

    public String getCard_brand() {
        return card_brand;
    }

    public void setCard_brand(String card_brand) {
        this.card_brand = card_brand;
    }
}
```

But I get error: `The method entrySet() is undefined for the type ArrayList<String>` What is the proper wya to map ArrayList?

Comment: Call `stream()`  directly on the list .

Comment: I get now The method getValue() is undefined for the type String

Comment: a List is not a Map, a Map has an entrySet method, a List does not. How hard is that to understand?

Comment: How to fix the next error?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rest endpoint should look like the following:

```
@GetMapping("/card_brand/list")
public ResponseEntity<List<CardBrandsListDTO>> getCurruncy() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(cardBrandsListService.getCardBrandsList().stream()
            .map(g -> new CardBrandsListDTO(g)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

You are calling `entrySet()`, which is used to get a Set of entries of a Map object (which you don't have). Additionally, inside the map function, your variable `g` is a String (since you are returning an `ArrayList<String>`), therefore you can directly supply that to the constructor. And you can directly set the correct type for the `ResponseEntity` as well.

UPDATE:

And you need the corresponding constructor:

```
public class CardBrandsListDTO {

    private String card_brand;

    public CarBrandsListDTO(String card_brand) {
        this.car_brand = car_brand;
    }

    //getter and setter
}
```

By the way, I would advise you to rename the DTO (for understandability) and also the field inside it (to follow naming conventions)

Comment: I get The constructor CardBrandsListDTO(String) is undefined

Comment: Is there a solution without adding a constructor in CardBrandsListDTO?

Comment: Yep, which would look like:

.map(g -> {
    CardBrandsListDTO dto = new CardBrandsListDTO();
    dto.setCard_brand(dto);

    return dto;
}